# IIS denying access to simple HTML file in virtual directory

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm trying to display simple HTML files in a folder on my web site. No ASP.NET, no application, just a virtual directory. I'm getting "Access denied" in the browser when I try to open a web page.

This is through a hosting provider; I have access through FTP and IIS Manager only.

Authorization Rules show Allow - All Users - Inherited.

I'm far from an expert on IIS, and most search results either suggest checking folder permissions in the file system (which I have no direct access to) or are relevant to applications.

How can I diagnose this?

---

**More information:**

Through trial and error, I found out the cause, and worked around it with URL Rewrite. I'd still like to know **why** it's happening (the root cause) and how to change IIS's behavior.

I'm moving my site from Linux hosting to Windows hosting. Some of the old URLs are of the form:

```
http://www.MYSITE/myblog/index.php/2013/04/29/SOMEFILE.html
```

The ones I'm moving are HTML files, not PHP files, but I tried to mirror the folder structure.

The problem is in the `index.php` folder name. No matter what I do, even if I enable directory browsing, IIS won't let me access any files in a folder with that name. If I rename the folder (or even the "extension" part), it all works.

I've scanned through many of the IIS settings and haven't found any mention of forbidding a .php extension. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error, I found out the cause, and worked around it with URL Rewrite.

For URLs of the form:

http://www.MYSITE/myblog/index.php/2013/04/29/SOMEFILE.html

The problem is in the `index.php` folder name. IIS won't let me access any files in a folder with that name. If I rename the folder (or even the "extension" part), it all works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add permission for IIS users.Try adding permission to the folder by adding user 
**IIS_IUSRS** and give required permission .

1.Right click on folder, go to properties
2.Go to security tab
3.Click on Edit, if you don't see IIS_IUSRS in the user list who have permission
4.Click on Add , In the box , add IIS_IUSRS and click on check names, it will 
get the qualified name .
5.Click OK and apply

Hopefully it should work then

Comment: Please note that I have access through FTP and IIS Manager only, as stated in my post. I cannot browse the file system with Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This is reminiscent of Joomla virtual (SEO) URLs. I'm assuming that you don't really have static files at all, but the CMS program running your site parses this information after the "index.php" as parameters for a database query to create the html page on the fly. In this case, the only file that's really being served by the web server is index.php, and the program includes other php files depending on the parameters entered. You're on the right track though, with creating a small file on the destination server and try to load it, but this means the index.php directory structure is moot.